# How to retrieve sqlite data using nodejs and display it in browser

Tags: sql, node.js, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart project which uses SQLite database. How do I retrieve sqlite data using nodejs and display it in browser? I have tried the following code. I am getting a blank or null result. Please help me.

```
<!-- language: index.js-->
//index.js
.get('/products', (req, res) => 
{
  var productsArr = Array(db.each('SELECT name, description, image, price FROM Product'),[],(err,rows) =>
  {
    if (err)
    {
      throw err;
    }
    rows.forEach( (row) => { console.log(rows); } );
  });
  res.render('pages/products', {products: productsArr})
})

//products.ejs
<section>
  <% if (products.length){%>
    <% products.forEach(function(item) {%>
      <div class="card" style="width:18rem;">
        <img class ="card-img-top" src ="images/<%=item.image %>" alt="some `enter code here` comment">
        <div class = "card-body text-center">
          <h5><%=item.name%>&nbsp;$<%=item.price %></h5>
          <p class ="card-text"><%=item.description%></p>
          <a href="#" class "btn btn-primary" onclick="addItem(<%= item.id %>);">Add</a>
          <a href="#" class "btn btn-danger" onclick="removeItem(<%= item.id %>);">Remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%})%>
  <%}%>
</section>
```

Comment: You are `console.log`ging `rows` inside the forEach function of rows array. Is that a typo ?

Comment: I am trying to display the content of each row in browser instead of console